# Unknown table 'BATCH_JOB_SEQ' in field list

Tags: java, mysql, spring-batch

I'm running :

- Spring Batch 2.2.7-RELEASE
- MySQL 5.6.17
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar

I created a new database for Spring batch metada, using the `schema-mysql.sql` file provided in `org.springframework.batch.core` package of Spring Batch 2.2.7-RELEASE.

I configured my transactionManager with the following configuration :

```
batch.db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
batch.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase
batch.db.user=myRootUser
batch.db.password=myRootPassword
```

When I try to run a job, I get the following error :

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain sequence value; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQL
SyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'BATCH_JOB_SEQ' in field list
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.java:79)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:1
25)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:98)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy5.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:124)
        at com.tinqin.deliverymanager.batch.executor.OneJobExecutor.execute(OneJobExecutor.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.tinqin.deliverymanager.batch.RunBatch.main(RunBatch.java:37)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'BATCH_JOB_SEQ' in field list
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1383)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.java:70)
        ... 25 more
```

Checking the database content, I do see the table `BATCH_JOB_SEQ` with a single entry (0,0).

Using `DEBUG` log level, the lines right before the stacktrace are as follow :

```
DEBUG [DataSourceUtils] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [DriverManagerDataSource] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase]
DEBUG [DataSourceUtils] - Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection
DEBUG [JdbcTemplate] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [JdbcTemplate] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME =
 ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
DEBUG [DataSourceUtils] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [DataSourceTransactionManager] - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG [DataSourceTransactionManager] - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@b7a85a]
DEBUG [DataSourceUtils] - Resetting isolation level of JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@b7a85a] to 4
DEBUG [DataSourceTransactionManager] - Releasing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@b7a85a] after transaction
DEBUG [DataSourceUtils] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

Now the odd thing is that the query executed doesn't contain any reference to `BATCH_JOB_SEQ` nor does the whole execution log.

What could be the cause and how can I correct it? Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-metadata-tables-are-not-created-automatically/

Comment: @BhargavKumarR Thanks, but as I said, I already used the provided database creation scripts. And I checked that the tables do exist.

Comment: Hey, i'm facing the same issue. any update?